# How do I process multiple string node command line arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I am developing a web scraper and have successfully been able to retrieve back the information from the site. 
The only issue is I need help on how to pass multiple command line arguments which will allow more data to be returned in my case I want to pass in multiple music artists to return what was found on the website.

I have tried using a for loop for the number of command line arguments. Then tried using a foreach loop.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
const args = process.argv.slice(2);


//request function that uses three parameters were we check for the error and response type

request(' https://www.billboard.com/charts/rap-song', function (error, response, html){ 
    if(!error && response.statusCode === 200) { 
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);


        var results = $('div').find('.chart-list-item__artist:contains("'+ artist +'")').each(function () { 
            // console.log($(this).text());
        }).text();
});
```

Maybe its because the contains operator can only process one command line argument? Or only gets the first artists specified.

```
Expected output: node artists.js "Post Malone" "Lil Baby"
----------------
Post Malone & Swae Lee

Post Malone

Lil Baby

Yo Gotti Featuring Lil Baby



Actual Output: node artists.js "Post Malone" "Lil Baby"
--------------
Post Malone & Swae Lee

Post Malone
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see you should iterate the artists and check for a match for each of them, instead of iterating the elements after matching just one artist.

I think something like this - based on what you have

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
const args = process.argv.slice(2);


//request function that uses three parameters were we check for the error and response type

request(' https://www.billboard.com/charts/rap-song', function (error, response, html){ 
  if(!error && response.statusCode === 200) { 
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);

    var results = [];
    args.forEach(artist => {
      $('div').find('.chart-list-item__artist:contains("'+ artist +'")').each(function () { 
          // console.log($(this).text());
          results.push(this); // push current element into results
      }).text();
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: Hmmm is there maybe another way of doing this without an array? :O

Comment: well you can console.log just fine without using the array... but otherwise I need to know what your goal is to figure out if you can do it without an array.

Comment: Basically I want to return artists that are from the site based on the artist that is specified within the command line argument. Right now I can only return one artist at a time

Comment: @B.Allen where I do `results.push` just do `console.log` - it should find the different artists

Comment: I get it now! The args variable uses the foreach object and uses the artists as a parameter to keep iterating over the number of arguments being passed to it! thus having the console.log which prints out the results instead of storing them into an array! Thank you so much!

Comment: @B.Allen glad this helped! process.argv acts like any other array once you `.slice()` if you want to see an official explanation for how to use arrays I recommend https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array